# How to dismiss a DialogFragment when pressing outside the dialog?

Tags: android, fragment, dismiss

I am using a `DialogFragment`, and while I have successfully set an image to close (i.e. dismiss) the dialog when pressed, I am having a hard time finding the way to dismiss the dialog when the user clicks anywhere outside it, just as it works with normal dialogs. I thought there would be some sort of

```
dialogFragment.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

call, but I don't see that in the documentation.

Is this possible with `DialogFragment` at all? Or am I looking in the wrong places? I tried intercepting touch events in the 'parent' activity but apart from not getting any touch event, it didn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Must be called in `onCreateView` (as Apurv Gupta pointed out).

Comment: Must be called in `onCreateView`

Comment: What if I don't want it to cancel but instead just close?

Comment: If you are modifying the dialog window try to add the this code in onResume() callback

Comment: Better call it in `onCreateDialog`. This method is responsible for configuring dialog.

Answer (score 59):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
       ... 
       }
```

Answer (score 21):

```
    /** The system calls this only when creating the layout in a dialog. */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The only reason you might override this method when using onCreateView() is
        // to modify any dialog characteristics. For example, the dialog includes a
        // title by default, but your custom layout might not need it. So here you can
        // remove the dialog title, but you must call the superclass to get the Dialog.
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. I had to call `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` in `onCreateView` as per @Apurv. I should mention that I called `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`

Answer (score 10):

Lot of answers here but, the app crash when dialog opens.
Writing `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` inside `onCreateView` did not work and crashed my app.

(I am using `AppCompatActivity` as my BaseActivity and `android.app.DialogFragment` as my Fragment).

What works is either of the two following lines:

> getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

OR

> this.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

inside `onActivityCreated` like

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationZoom;
        //getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0.85f);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);//See here is the code
    }
```

What not to use:

> DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

throws following error

[image]

And writing the code in `onCreateView` crashes the App!
Please update the answer if you find something wrong.

Comment: Probably this is because you create a dialog inside `onCreateDialog()`, where it is a usual way of initialization. In this case `onCreateView()` does nothing and even doesn't contain a view. You can try to move the code to `onCreateDialog()`.

Comment: @CoolMind Oh that's a nice observation. Will surely keep this in my try list. Thanks!

Comment: I think, your answer, nevertheless, makes sence, and 4 people marked pluses. I also experienced problems with `onCreateDialog`, `onCreateView` in near past. Maybe I am wrong, and you should retain `onActivityCreated`, it is a nice method to make additional initialization (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734566/2914140, for example).

Comment: @CoolMind nice that works for you. But I can notice that, problems that you are experiencing are because of your `BottomSheet` implementation. It might be different in case of BSheet I agree. But this solution for a `DialogFragment` does work well.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to execute some logic when clicking outside of a `DialogFragment`, just override the onCancel method.

```
override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onCancel(dialog)
    // Do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for Java:

```
DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: But who asked anything about Mono? :/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use my solution only after trying out above solutions. I have described my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043015/2049781). Just to brief, I am checking touch bounds of DialogFragment.getView(). When touch points are outside DialogFragment, I am dismissing the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Worked for me
My Code

```
class dlgRegister : DialogFragment
        {
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
    ....
    ....
    }
    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations =    Resource.Style.dialog_animation;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        DialogConfermationdialogBinding binding = DialogConfermationdialogBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return view;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).