# android: How can i close fragment when the user touch outside of it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Hi everybody =) i am a new android developer and i need a help about dismissing fragment.

My application have an login fragment and when the user touch the outside of it i want to hide login fragment. How can i make this? OnTouchEvent() method may be useful or not?

Please say something. Thanks =)

Comment: If you are using a DialogFragment you can use the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140

Comment: Thanks,but it is not a DialogFragment..

Comment: Why don't you use a dialogfragment? it seems like that would make more sense anyways since you want to have it appear like a dialog and behave like one..

Comment: yes it seems more useful, i try it,but my application crashes with error illegalstateexception with dialog fragment.

Answer (score 1):

place the login layout inside a transparent, full screen layout, and detect touch events on the larger layout.

Answer (score 0):

Hi again =) i solve this problem using OnTouchListener on my Homepage activity.I have an gridviews background in my homepage layout and if the user doesn't login, `onTouch()` method runs.When the login fragment is visible and the user touch outside of it my hideLoginFragment() method calling for dismissing the fragment..

```
gridView = (ShelvesView) findViewById(R.id.grid_shelves);
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (application.getDbManager().getUser().key.equals("-1")){
                    hideLoginFragment();
                    loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    exitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is removing fragment in order to release memory resources.

My solution is having having this method in fragment:

```
private void closeFragment() {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(YOUR_FRAGMENT.this).commit();
    }
```