# Preventing WebView from closing when clicked outside the webview

Tags: android, webview

In my app, I load a WebView where users enter username/password and I don't want the webview to close should the users accidentally click outside of the webview since the page will have to make another network call to load this webview.

I know this can be done for Dialog (like so: `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`) but couldn't find similar mechanism for webview.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class LoginDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = LoginDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();

View mainView = null;
WebView webView = null;
OnLoginSucceeded loginSucceeded = null;

ProgressBar progressBar = null;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

    if (getDialog() != null)
        getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.login));

    webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    //display the progress bar
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_loading_progress);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //turn caching off
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i(TAG, "URL received in onCreateView's onPageStarted is: " + url);
            new HandleRequest().execute(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });

    new FetchLoginFormTask().execute();

    return mainView;
}
```

Comment: In which widget you are opening the webview ? Any Dialog or anything..... ??  Please set like setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) instead of true. And  have you try with setCancelable(false) ??

Comment: @iDroidExplorer this webview is being shown in a View which itself is part of a DialogFragment and hence I can't use the methods you suggested.

Comment: I updated my post w/ the code I am referring to.

Comment: Can you please also put the code about how you are loading the url. And i would also like to know What is FetchLoginFormTask() and HandleRequest() ?

Answer (score 1):

[I found my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-when-pressing-outside-the-dialog) and I just used `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` ensuring that when back key is clicked, the webview is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with override the method:

```
    @Override
public void setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {

    super.setCancelable(false);
}
```

If your issue is not getting solved by this then please put some code so i can help you.

Feel free for comment.

Comment: Overriding setCancelable doesn't actually help since I want a similar functionality as `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` and I am extending DialogFragment and not Dialog. The FetchLoginFormTask() and HandleRequest() are methods that display the login w/ the identity providers such as Google, Facebook.