# How to close a Dialog Fragment On Clicking outside the Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, mobile-application

I have gone through many of the suggestion for this in stack and couldn't still resolve my issue. I was using a Dialog fragment `TestFragment` which is getting called from my `AFragment` class and the `TestFragment` is shown on top of the `AFragment` .Currently on clicking outside of the screen, I have to close the `TestFragment`. currently it is not getting closed. please find the below code.
`DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); I'm getting the following error Non-static method 'getDialog()' cannot be referenced from a static context` -> Couldnt resolve with this solution also.
AFragment :

```
FragmentTransaction ft =    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   testfragment testfragments = new testfragment();
                   testfragments.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                   ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                   ft.addToBackStack("filterPriceFragment");
                   ft.replace(R.id.filter_pop_up_frame_lyt, testfragments, "filterPriceFragment");
                   ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

`TestFragment`:

```
public class testfragment extends DialogFragment {


    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.MyApplyButton);
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

        View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_price_fragment_lyt, container, false);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-when-pressing-outside-the-dialog

Comment: Put it inside `onCreateView` as per the suggestion from above thread

Comment: @gtxtreme - I have tried that also, when I put the same code on onCreateView like this    `DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` I'm getting the following error `Non-static method 'getDialog()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: You should add this in your question.`I couldn't resolve this issue` doesn't help us with what exactly your question is

Comment: @gtxtreme - Updated the same above.

Comment: Also did you try with `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`?

Comment: @gtxtreme - let me try that now.

Comment: @gtxtreme -  `getDialog.setCanceltedOnTouchOutside(true)` throws an error for me .     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Have you used it in `onCreateView`?

Comment: @gtxtreme - yes.   `public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.MyApplyButton);
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
       View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_price_fragment_lyt, container, false);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        return view;`

Comment: @gtxtreme - any updates on this??

Comment: There are so many answers in the pointed link, why don't you try them out one by one?

Comment: @gtxtreme - tried everything, not solving any of the solutions